# Azure Service Bus features

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I've got some question about Azure Service Bus functionalities.

1. If I use PartitionKey in my Topic that will handle the order of the messages in that specific partition. I've found some articles about the problem ( https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-partitioning.md) but i just want to use simple Client.OnMessage method to handle the messages. Is there a way to handle this it a clear way or I need to use Session based message handling?

PartitionKey: If a message has the BrokeredMessage.PartitionKey property but not the BrokeredMessage.SessionId property set, then Service Bus uses the PartitionKey property as the partition key. If the message has both the SessionId and the PartitionKey properties set, both properties must be identical. If the PartitionKey property is set to a different value than the SessionId property, Service Bus returns an InvalidOperationException exception. The PartitionKey property should be used if a sender sends non-session aware transactional messages. **The partition key ensures that all messages that are sent within a transaction are handled by the same messaging broker.**

If the message always handle by the same message broker that not means inside the partition the order stay the same? I just want to handle this case.

2. Is there a way to replace / update a message in the Service Bus if the MessageId equals. Basically, if there is a message in service bus that get an update from my application and client not handled yet I just want to update that message. I know that is not a normal way of doing things in service bus architecture.